# unwanted array in output, pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have the following code giving me almost exactly what I want:

```
def stateCountAsList(filepath,state):

    import pandas as pd 
    pd.set_option('display.width',200)

    import numpy as np 

    dataFrame = pd.read_csv(filepath,header=0,sep='\t')
    df = dataFrame.iloc[0:638,:]

    dfState = df[df['State']== state]
    yearList = range(1999,2012)
    countsList =[]

    for year in yearList: #for every year in the range 
        if year in dfState['Year'].tolist(): #if the year is in the list of years for the selected state 
            value = dfState[(dfState.Year == year)]
            countsList.append(value.Count.values) 
        else: 
            countsList.append(np.nan.values)
    print countsList 
    return countsList

stateCountAsList('United States Cancer Statistics, 1999-2011 Incidencet.txt' ,'California')
```

.

The issue is that my out put is supposed to be a list, but i get the word array everywhere:

```
[array([ 5561.]), array([ 5588.]), array([ 6059.]), array([ 6043.]), array([ 5958.]), array([ 6566.]), array([ 7160.]), array([ 6780.]), array([ 7327.]), array([ 7585.]), array([ 7483.]), array([ 7635.]), array([ 7735.])]
```

How do i remove the array in my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panda's Dataframe stores its data in numpy arrays. Which is why you are seeing the word array in the output. You can call `tolist()` if you want to convert it to plain python lists instead of numpy arrays.

```
# untested
for year in yearList: #for every year in the range 
    if year in dfState['Year'].tolist(): #if the year is in the list of years for the selected state 
        value = dfState[(dfState.Year == year)]
        countsList.append(value.Count.values.tolist()) 
    else: 
        countsList.append(np.nan.values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

An `array` is a data structure created by the NumPy library, which is a scientific library for Python. One can retrieve items from arrays and lists in a similar fashion.

Since `value.Count.values` and `np.nan.values` return arrays with one item, you can instead append the item to `countsList` directly:

```
countsList.append(value.Count.values[0])
...
countsList.append(np.nan.values[0])
```

Source: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html